# Stored procedure that returns a table from 2 combined

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

I am trying to write a stored procedure which returns a result combining 2 table variables which looks something like this.

```
Name | LastName | course | course | course  | course  <- Columns
Name | LastName | DVA123 | DVA222 | nothing | nothing <- Row1
Pete   Steven       200                               <- Row2    
Steve  Lastname              50                       <- Row3
```

From these 3 tables

Table **Staff**:

```
Name | LastName | SSN |
Steve  Lastname   234 
Pete   Steven     132
```

Table **Course Instance**:

```
Course | Year | Period |
DVA123   2013     1 
DVA222   2014     2
```

Table **Attended by**:

```
Course | SSN |  Year  | Period | Hours |
DVA123   234    2013      1       200 
DVA222   132    2014      2       50
```

I am taking `@year` as a parameter that will decide what year in the course will be displayed in the result.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[test4]
   @year int
as
begin

-- I then declare the 2 tables which I will then store the values from the tables
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE( 
   Firstname varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
   Lastname varchar(30) NOT NULL 
); 

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE( 
   Course varchar(30) NULL
);
```

Declare @variable varchar(max) -- variable for saving the cursor value and then set the course1 to 4

I want at highest 4 results/course instances which I later order by the period of the year

```
declare myCursor1 CURSOR
for SELECT top 4 period from Course instance
where year = @year

open myCursor1

fetch next from myCursor1 into @variable
--print @variable

while @@fetch_status = 0
    Begin

    UPDATE @Table2
    SET InstanceCourse1 = @variable
    where current of myCursor1

    fetch next from myCursor1 into @variable
    print @variable

    End

Close myCursor1
deallocate myCursor1

insert into @table1
select 'Firstname', 'Lastname'

insert into @table1
select Firstname, Lastname from staff order by Lastname

END

select * from @Table1 -- for testing purposes
select * from @Table2 -- for testing purposes
--Then i want to combine these tables into the output at the top
```

This is how far I've gotten, I don't know how to get the courses into the columns and then get the amount of hours for each staff member.

If anyone can help guide me in the right direction I would be very grateful. My idea about the cursor was to get the top (0-4) values from the top4 course periods during that year and then add them to the `@table2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. This is not pretty. It is a really ugly dynamic sql, but in my testing it seems to be working. I have created an extra subquery to get the courses values as the first row and then Union with the rest of the result. The top four courses are gathered by using ROW_Number() and order by Year and period. I had to make different versions of the courses string I am creating in order to use them for both column names, and in my pivot. Give it a try. Hopefully it will work on your data as well.

```
DECLARE @Year INT
SET @Year = 2014
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(2000)

DECLARE @CoursesColumns NVARCHAR(2000) 
SET @CoursesColumns = (SELECT '''' + Course + ''' as c' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Year,     Period) AS nvarchar(50)) + ',' AS 'data()'
FROM AttendedBy where [Year] = @Year
for xml path(''))
SET @CoursesColumns = LEFT(@CoursesColumns, LEN(@CoursesColumns) -1)
SET @CoursesColumns = 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c1', @CoursesColumns) = 0 THEN @CoursesColumns + 'NULL as c1, NULL as c2, NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c2', @CoursesColumns) = 0 THEN @CoursesColumns + ',NULL as c2, NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c3', @CoursesColumns) = 0 THEN @CoursesColumns + ', NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c4', @CoursesColumns) = 0 THEN @CoursesColumns + ', NULL as c4'
    ELSE @CoursesColumns
END

DECLARE @Courses NVARCHAR(2000) 
SET @Courses = (SELECT Course + ' as c' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Year, Period) AS     nvarchar(50)) + ',' AS 'data()'
FROM AttendedBy where [Year] = @Year
for xml path(''))
SET @Courses = LEFT(@Courses, LEN(@Courses) -1)
SET @Courses = 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c1', @Courses) = 0 THEN @Courses + 'NULL as c1, NULL as c2, NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c2', @Courses) = 0 THEN @Courses + ',NULL as c2, NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c3', @Courses) = 0 THEN @Courses + ', NULL as c3, NULL as c4'
    WHEN CHARINDEX('c4', @Courses) = 0 THEN @Courses + ', NULL as c4'
    ELSE @Courses
END

DECLARE @CoursePivot NVARCHAR(2000) 
SET @CoursePivot = (SELECT  Course + ',' AS 'data()'
FROM AttendedBy where [Year] = @Year
for xml path(''))
SET @CoursePivot = LEFT(@CoursePivot, LEN(@CoursePivot) -1)

SET @Query = 'SELECT Name, LastName, c1, c2, c3, c4
FROM (
SELECT ''Name'' as name, ''LastName'' as lastname, ' +  @CoursesColumns +
' UNION

SELECT Name, LastName,' + @Courses +
' FROM(

SELECT 
    s.Name
    ,s.LastName
    ,ci.Course
    ,ci.Year
    ,ci.Period
    ,CAST(ab.Hours AS NVARCHAR(100)) AS Hours
FROM Staff s
LEFT JOIN AttendedBy ab
ON
s.SSN = ab.SSN
LEFT JOIN CourseInstance ci
ON
ab.Course = ci.Course
WHERE ci.Year=' + CAST(@Year AS nvarchar(4)) +
' ) q
PIVOT(
    MAX(Hours)
FOR 
    Course
IN (' + @CoursePivot + ')
)q2
)q3'


SELECT @Query
execute(@Query)
```

Edit: Added some where clauses so only courses from given year is shown. Added Screenshot of my results.
[image]

Comment: Got an error which states: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'dva123' to data type int. This is when i execute the procedure not creating it. Any idea which part of the code which makes this casting and how to fix it?

Comment: Seems like I for some reason when creting my tables had made the Hours column as a NVARCHAR, not INT which it should be. When changing this to INT I was able to recreate your message. It comes from during the pivot. By casting the Hours column to nvarchar earlier in the query we should be able to get the pivot correct. Updated my answer. Hopefully it will work for you this time.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DECLARE @CourseNameString varchar(max),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @CourseNameString=''
select @CourseNameString = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Course) 
                   FROM Attended where [Year]= 2013
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = '
select Name,LastName,'+@CourseNameString+' from Staff as e inner join (

 SELECT * FROM
(SELECT [Hours],a.SSN,a.Course as c FROM Attended as a inner JOIN Staff as s
ON s.SSN = s.SSN) p
PIVOT(max([Hours])FOR c IN ('+@CourseNameString+')) pvt)p
 ON e.SSN = p.SSN'

  execute(@query)
```

Comment: This returned a result like this: |Firstname|Lastname|DVA123|DVA222| <- Columns, then |Pete|Steven|200|null and |Steven|Lastname|null|50 on row1 and 2. Can i somehow modify this so i get the value from the columns into the first row aswell? Look at the example output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery like this one  :

```
SELECT Firstname, Lastname, (select instanceCourse1 from table2) as InstanceCourse1 from Table1
```